# PHP: unexpected T_VARIABLE error

Tags: php

I made this tutorial for an anti leech script in PHP:
http://tanksoftware.com/tutes/leechprotection.html

Now by testing the php file online I become this error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /www/htdocs/myfolder/download.php on line 14
>   What is wrong on that line?

This is the code:

```
function generateSymLink($directory, $offset = 0) {
        $day = "";

        //todays day of the month, eg "14"
        $day = date("d", time() + (24*3600*$offset));  

        // A string which would look somthing like this "Monday, 14 Jan 2003MySecretKey/myfiles/example"
        $tohash = date("D, d M Y", time() + (24*3600*$offset))."My Secret Key".$directory

        // The first seven digits of the hash of the above string which would look somthing like
        // "a4h1b".
        $smallkey = substr(md5($tohash),0,5);

        return $day.$smallkey;
    }



// extracts the file details
    $fullpath = "myfiles/example/file.tar.gz";
    $seperated = explode("/", $row['Filename']);
    $actualfile = $seperated[sizeof($seperated)-1];
    $path = substr($fullpath, 0,(strlen($fullpath)-strlen($actualfile)));



// Gets the current working directory
    $wd = getcwd();

    // Enters the download directory
    chdir("dl") or die("Unable to enter the download directory");

    // Creates a new symlink if nessesary
    if (!file_exists(getSymLink($path)))
        symlink("../".$path, getSymLink($path)) or die("Unable to create download link");

    // changes back to the directory of the script
    chdir ($wd);

// Returns the current day of the month
    function getDnum($offset = 0) {
        return date("d", time() + (24*3600*$offset));
    }



    // removes old symbolic links
    function cleanUpOldSymlinks () {

        // Only execute this code 1/10th of the time (to conserve CPU time).
        $randomNumber = rand(0,10);
        if ($randomNumber != 6)
            return;

        // enters the download directory
        $wd = getcwd();
        chdir("dl") or die ("Unable to enter directory dl");


        // Deletes all symlinks that are not current
        // As a symlink is only current for a maximum of 48 hours - and due to the
        // hashing they are never repeated - this should effectivly prevent leeching.
        if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {

                // extracts the date of the symlink
                $dateOfLink = substr($file,0,2);

                // checks to see if it's current
                if (($dateOfLink != getDnum(0)) && ($dateOfLink != getDnum(-1)) && strlen($file) > 2) {

                    // Removes the symlink
                    unlink($file);
                }
            } 
            }
            closedir($handle); 
        }

        chdir ($wd);
    }   



    function getDownloadKey($file, $offset) {
        return generateSymLink($file, $offset);
    }

    $file = getFilepathFromID($_GET['fileid']);
    $key = $_GET['key'];
    if ($key != getDownloadKey($file, 0) && $key != getDownloadKey($file, -1))
        die ("invalid download key");

    // else - download the file
    // ...

    ?>
```

The tutorial is way too complex for my english skills and PHP expierence but I need such an "anti leech script" to protect my downloads. 
So any tips and help is very welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Which one is 14th line ?

Answer (score 3):

You forgot a semicolon at the end.

```
$tohash = date("D, d M Y", time() + (24*3600*$offset))."My Secret Key".$directory;
```

Comment: OK but now I receive this error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function getsymlink() in /www/htdocs/download.php on line 36` Is that tutorial good at all? I'm not sure if it's complete.